# Creating TrueCrypt volumes on Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, truecrypt

Currently it is not possible to create TrueCrypt volumes using the command line on Windows. According to the official website, this is "planned to be implemented in the future" (see: http://www.truecrypt.org/future).

For an autmated script I want to create multiple TrueCrypt volumes on a daily base. Is there any work around or any other solution to create TrueCrypt volumes on Windows? Linux is not an option, it has to be Windows.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference. I was looking into this and apparently is not possible yet...
http://www.truecrypt.org/future

Answer (score 0):

I think you should automate the GUI with any of the GUI-scripting tools available until truecrypt will update their command line options. I was searching a little in the web and found this:

http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/151825-truecrypt-volume-creation-automation/

I haven't checked it out, but maybe it can help you somehow...
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As a possible workaround, you can once manually create truecrypt container. Than copy it and work with the copy. You can automate mounting, copying data to mounted volume, dismounting and so on.

Answer (score -1):

Use a `/q` parameter. See [here](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=command-line-usage). Example: `"C:\Program Files\TrueCrypt\TrueCrypt.exe" /q /lT /v "C:\mydata.tc"`.

Comment: This command still requires user input. I am looking for a way to create volumes, using the console, without showing a single UI.